# Make a <td> span the entire row in a table

Tags: html, html-table

I'm not new to HTML but haven't touched it for some good time and I've encountered an annoying problem.

I have a table with two rows.
I want the first row to have one column - means that it will span the entire row, and I want the second row to have three columns, each one 33.3% of the row's width.

I have this code for the table :

```
<table width="900px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">check</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">check</td>
        <td align="center">check</td>
        <td align="center">check</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But what happens is weird, the first row has one column with the same size as the second row's first column, and whenever I change one of them, it changes the other one too.

If I give the first row's `<td>` the width value of `500px` lets say, it sets the second row's first `<td>` to the same size.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You should use the `colspan` attribute on the first row's td.
`Colspan="3"` will set the cell to flow over 3 columns.

```
<table width="900px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="3">check</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">check</td>
        <td align="center">check</td>
        <td align="center">check</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 8):

You want to use the `colspan` attribute like this:

```html
 <table width="900px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="3">check</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" >check</td>
       <td align="center">check</td>
       <td align="center">check</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use colspan

```
<td align="center" colspan="3">check</td>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp

Answer (score 5):

If you're using **JSX** (*React*) it should be written like this. The `s` in `colspan` is capitalized and the value is a number instead of a string.

```
<td colSpan={3}>Text</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using colspan like this:

```
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="3">check</td>
    </tr>
```

By colspan you merge the following cells in a row to one. If you use 2 in your sample you get one cell with a width of the first two columns and the third is as the third in the rest of the table.

Answer (score 1):

alter the first row with the below

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="center">check</td>
</tr>
```