# Expand a textarea across table HTML

Tags: html

I am trying to add a text area within a table but it only fits in one column but I want to expand to cover the whole width of all columns.
Currently is shown as:
[image]

My Code:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Criteria 1</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="experiencebx1" required value="1" id="experiencebx1_1" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="experiencebx1" value="2" id="experiencebx1_2" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="experiencebx1" value="3" id="experiencebx1_3" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="experiencebx1" value="4" id="experiencebx1_4" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="experiencebx1" value="5" id="experiencebx1_5" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="experiencebx1" value="6" id="experiencebx1_6" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="experiencebx1" value="7" id="experiencebx1_7" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="experiencebx1" value="8" id="experiencebx1_8" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="experiencebx1" value="9" id="experiencebx1_9" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="experiencebx1" value="10" id="experiencebx1_10" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Comments: </td>
    <td><textarea required name="Comments"></textarea> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a <td> span the entire row in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26400006/make-a-td-span-the-entire-row-in-a-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you need to set the width on the text area to 100% and make the table cell it's in span the other columns with `<td colspan="10">`:

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Criteria 1</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="experiencebx1" required value="1" id="experiencebx1_1" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="experiencebx1" value="2" id="experiencebx1_2" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="experiencebx1" value="3" id="experiencebx1_3" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="experiencebx1" value="4" id="experiencebx1_4" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="experiencebx1" value="5" id="experiencebx1_5" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="experiencebx1" value="6" id="experiencebx1_6" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="experiencebx1" value="7" id="experiencebx1_7" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="experiencebx1" value="8" id="experiencebx1_8" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="experiencebx1" value="9" id="experiencebx1_9" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="experiencebx1" value="10" id="experiencebx1_10" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Comments: </td>
    <td colspan="10"><textarea required name="Comments"></textarea> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Seriously? No dupe even for `colspan`?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your HTML to add a colspan

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Criteria 1</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="experiencebx1" required value="1" id="experiencebx1_1" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="experiencebx1" value="2" id="experiencebx1_2" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="experiencebx1" value="3" id="experiencebx1_3" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="experiencebx1" value="4" id="experiencebx1_4" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="experiencebx1" value="5" id="experiencebx1_5" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="experiencebx1" value="6" id="experiencebx1_6" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="experiencebx1" value="7" id="experiencebx1_7" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="experiencebx1" value="8" id="experiencebx1_8" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="experiencebx1" value="9" id="experiencebx1_9" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="experiencebx1" value="10" id="experiencebx1_10" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Comments: </td>
    <td colspan="10">
      <textarea required name="Comments"></textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You'll also need to update your CSS to make it 100% width:

```
td textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
```